# rails 4 deployment - rake stderr: config.eager_load is set to nil .. incorrect error message

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, deployment

during a project staging deployment w Capistrano, with a common db access error to be solved, I noticed  the rake stderr line :

```
  rake stderr: config.eager_load is set to nil. Please update your config/environments/*.rb files accordingly..
```

however , my config/environments/*rb files are correctly set as required..
why this message ? what did I missed ?

my config/environments/development.rb

```
 config.eager_load = false
```

my config/environments/production.rb

```
 config.eager_load = true
```

my config/environments/test.rb

```
config.eager_load = false
```

here is the extract from the console log

```
    Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
    (See full trace by running task with --trace)

    SSHKit::Command::Failed: rake exit status: 1
    rake stdout: Nothing written
    rake stderr: config.eager_load is set to nil. Please update your config/environments/*.rb files accordingly:

      * development - set it to false
      * test - set it to false (unless you use a tool that preloads your test environment)
      * production - set it to true

    rake aborted!
    Mysql2::Error: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

Comment: Did you solve your problem? I think the main problem here is wrong MySQL credentials.

Comment: you're right, I had to manage my production/staging deployment credentials via a capistrano task ( setup:upload_yml) to upload the secrets.yml and database.yml into my remote server.... runnung fine now ...

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar issue when deploying with

```
cap staging deploy
```

The problem was that capistrano was looking for the database `myapp_staging`, while I needed `myapp_production`.

I fixed it by adding

```
set :stage, "production"
```

in `config/deploy/staging.rb`.

Answer (score 1):

(Answered in the comments. Converted to a community wiki answer. See [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments) )

@amoebe wrote:

> I think the main problem here is wrong MySQL credentials.

The OP wrote:

> you're right, I had to manage my production/staging deployment credentials via a `capistrano` task ( `setup:upload_yml`) to upload the `secrets.yml` and `database.ym`l into my remote server.... running fine now...